# "Key pressed Event" in appcelerator android is not working where it is working fine in i phone simulator

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

**i referred to the official appcelerator site and implemented the Text Field where i have set the "focusable" property to true and have added the key pressed event but it is not working.Kindly provide the solution in detail?**

index.xml:

```
<Text Field   id="txt_field" focusable = true/>
```

index.js:

```
$.txt_field.addEventListener('keypressed',function({

*********my code***********
});
```

Comment: there is a correction  .
$.txt_field.addEventListener("keypressed",function(e){
 
 
 Ti.API.info(" keyCode = " + e.keyCode);
});

Comment: I've answered, however you are completely unclear in mentioning what you want to achieve and how you detected it didn't work. So I had to guess a bit

Answer (score 3):

First, there seems to be a space in your xml, not sure if that is a typo. It should be this:

```
<TextField  id="txt_field" focusable="true" />
```

Next, the `keypressed` event only works with hardware keys. If you just want to know a new character was typed, you should use the `change` event.

Best practice is to also add the event listeners to the xml, and don't add them in javascript

```
<TextField  id="txt_field" focusable="true" onChange="changeTextField" />
```

Then you'll need to create a changeTextField function in your controller:

```
function changeTextField(e) {
    // the textfield will be in e.source
    // the new value of the textfield will be in e.value
}
```

based on that, you can check e.value and see what has changed as opposed to the last change.

Comment: yeah that was a typo but what if i need the keycode of the keyboard values. How can i use the change event instead of keypressed in this case?

Comment: compare value before and after the change to detect what has been typed. You don't get the keycode on virtual keyboards like you do in html

Comment: thanks for reaching out @Rene Pot but the keypressed event works fine in iOS with the virtual keyboard and i am able to get the key code value with "e.keyCode". In android when i tried it wasn't the case. even after setting the focusable value to true as instructed in the appcelerator site.